# How can I get this href by beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, tags, href, python-requests-html

I want to get a product url on this website:
https://stockx.com/search?s=555088-105

[the url i want to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgMzv.png)

But i try this code

```
link = soup.find("div", class_ = 'browse-grid loading undefined')
print(link)
```

It just return

```
<div class="browse-grid loading undefined"><div class="back-to-top"><div class="back-to-top-container"><img alt="back to top" src="https://stockx-assets.imgix.net/svg/icons/back-to-top.svg?auto=compress,format"/><span>TOP</span></div></div><div class="browse-grid"><div class="no-results">NOTHING TO SEE HERE! PLEASE CHANGE YOUR FILTERS OR <a href="/product-suggestion">Suggest a Product</a></div></div></div>
```

or i try this, it just print all the url without the url I want

```
a_tags = soup.find_all('a')
for tag in a_tags:
  print(tag.get('href'))
```

How can I get the url in my picture?

Comment: When I use BeautifulSoup it returns [<a href="https://www.perimeterx.com/whywasiblocked">PerimeterX</a>]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL you see on the page is loaded from external source via JavaScript - so `beautifulsoup` doesn't see it. You can simulate the Ajax requests with `requests` module:

```py
import re
import json
import requests

url = "https://stockx.com/search?s=555088-105"
api_url = "https://stockx.com/api/browse"

id_ = re.search(r"s=([\d-]+)", url).group(1)
params = {
    "": "",
    "currency": "EUR",
    "_search": id_,
    "dataType": "product",
}

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:88.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/88.0",
    "Referer": url,
}

data = requests.get(api_url, params=params, headers=headers).json()

# uncomment this to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

for product in data["Products"]:
    print("https://stockx.com/" + product["urlKey"])
```

Prints:

```
https://stockx.com/air-jordan-1-retro-high-dark-mocha
```

Comment: THX! it works, but want i try on some search link like this: https://stockx.com/search/sneakers?s=CT8527-400

python will retun this

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Python\Stockx\Stockx.py", line 49, in <module> 
    id_ = re.search(r"s=([\d-]+)", url).group(1)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'`

Comment: @Leung You can modify the regex to `s=([A-Z\d-]+)` (The idea is, you need only ID `CT8527-400` for the search)